# Rendering a gitbook and pdf_book with bookdown using kable and kableExtra

Tags: r, report, knitr, bookdown, kableextra

Please consider the following:

**Background**
I worked with the `bookdown` package and wrote the entire project in several .Rmd files. All tables are produced with `knitr::kable()` and `kableExtra::kable_styling()` to make them look readable.

To easily apply the same style to all tables I wrote a function to apply the desired `kableExtra::kable_styling()` arguments (`KableStyleFun`).

Merging a `gitbook` with the "M-K" approach is no problem. However, now I need to produce something more "shareable" and "printable" like a PDF document.

There is little information out there on how to do this without having to re-write the entire code.

Hao Zhu explains a possibility [here](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/bookdown/cross-format-tables-in-bookdown.html#use-the-k-m-approach-instead-of-m-k). However, this source is quite confusing since (I think) it mistakes the "M-K" for the "K-M" approach. It is stated that:

> To generate cross-format tables with `kableExtra` in a multi-format bookdown project, you will have to use the “M-K” approach by setting `new_session: true` in `_bookdown.yml`.

`new_session: true` actually initiates the "K-M" approach though. See [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/new-session.html).

Nevertheless, the "K-M" approach is no option for me since I "pass-on" objects from one chapter to another.

---

**Question**
How can I create a `pdf_book` with `bookdown` from the following example with a minimal adaptation to the code?

---

**Content of the file "01-render.Rmd"**

````
# First part

```{r echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

# Define function for all tables
KabelStyleFun <- function(dat){
        dat %>% kableExtra::kable_styling(full_width = F,
                                          latex_options = "striped",
                                          bootstrap_options = c("striped",
                                                                "hover"))
        }
```


Table \@ref(tab:test-tab1) in the `gitbook` renders well. But how can I make
this work in a `pdf_book`?

```{r test-tab1}
head(mtcars) %>%
         knitr::kable(caption = "testtab") %>%
         KabelStyleFun
```
````

---

**Content of the file '_bookdown.yml'**

```
book_filename: "test_book"
delete_merged_file: true
language:
  ui:
    chapter_name: "Section "
rmd_files: ["01-render.Rmd"]
```

---

**Rendered with**

`bookdown::render_book("01-render.Rmd", output_format = "bookdown::gitbook")` = No problem

`bookdown::render_book("01-render.Rmd", output_format = "bookdown::pdf_book")` =

> Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex output.
>   Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
>   HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
>   your rmarkdown file:
>     always_allow_html: yes
>   Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with `bookdown::render_book`. Using `bookdown::render_site` does work for me, though. BTW, I would add `booktabs = TRUE` to `knitr::kable()`.

Comment: Could you please specify? `render_site` is not an exported object from 'namespace:bookdown'. Maybe you mean `rmarkdown::render_site()`? In the latter case, do you get a PDF document of a HTML document? I get the error message `No site generator found.`

Comment: Yes, I meant `rmarkdown::render_site()`. You will need a file `index.Rmd` for it to work. Using `rmarkdown::render_site(output_format = 'bookdown::gitbook', encoding = 'UTF-8')` and `rmarkdown::render_site(output_format = 'bookdown::pdf_book', encoding = 'UTF-8')` I can produce both output formats. However, `rmarkdown::render_site(encoding = 'UTF-8')`, which should prouce all output formats, produces the same error.